# What is the origin of "your mother" as an answer to any question?

Tags: etymology, slang

I'm just curious, as the term "your mom" as an annoying answer/reaction to any question/comment is also used in other languages. So what is its etymology?

**UPDATE**

I even found a reference on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/45734/the-coolest-server-names/45941#45941).

Maybe it wasn't that clear what I meant, so I give two examples taken from the urban dictionary:

> Guy 1: I'm going to tie my shoes
>
> Guy 2: YO MOMA'S GONA TIE HER SHOES!!!

and

> Girl 1: That Girl is a slut.
>
> Random Guy 1: YO MOMA'S A SLUT!!!

I even remember an Episode from *Miami Vice* (season 3, maybe episode 22) where Crocked asks for the whereabouts of a suspect and he gets a kind of "Your Mom" as an answer.

Here's another reference:

[image]

Comment: In Mexico, [foreigners are advised never to say *madre*](http://laii.unm.edu:8000/Events/Madre_Press_Release.pdf) (standard Spanish for *mother*). Use the less controversial term *mama* or *mamá* instead. There are a few idioms or set phrases where it is acceptable, but they are so specific that it is better not to use the term at all.

Comment: @mbx, That's a different question. I'm withdrawing my former answer then.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Is this perhaps derived from the Russian all-purpose expression _fuck your mother_?

Comment: @Brian Hopper I don't think so since it seems to be used even without the sexual context. As I described it can be used as answer to anything - just like 42 or meh.

Comment: @mbx, I'm no authority on the subject, but I was under the impression that the Russian phrase meant about that...

Comment: @Brian Could you spell the Russian phrase? In fact, the use of "yo moma" or "deine mudda" might be derived from the vulgar version and lost that context somehow.

Comment: @mbx, the Russian is Ёб твою мать, which transliterates to _yob tvoyu mat’_. More here... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat_%28Russian_profanity%29

Comment: @Henry - After playing soccer with Latin American teammates for nearly a decade, pretty much the only Spanish I've managed to pick up is "Tu madre!"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Presumably people are generally assumed to be rather annoyed if the chastity of their mother is questioned?

Even the great rap-star Bill Shakespeare (from the West midlands massive) used it:

Demetrius: “Villain, what hast thou done?”
Aaron: “That which thou canst not undo.”
Chiron: “Thou hast undone our mother.”
Aaron: “Villain, I have done thy mother.”

Comment: Sadly his wide range of "your mother is so fat" jokes have been lost

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Maternal Insult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maternal_insult) includes this exchange, and is rather good.  It also points out the Spanish equivalent *“Y tu mamá también!”* (*“And your mother too!”*)

Answer (score 4):

Some people trace it to a centuries old African-American game of trading insults called "the dozens". https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/The_Dozens